# How to show a pdf file in a web page present on remote server

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I am trying to show a pdf file present on my web hosting on html page.

My code is :-

```
Dim WC As WebClient = New WebClient()
WC.UseDefaultCredentials = False
Dim CREDS As CredentialCache = New CredentialCache()

CREDS.Add(New Uri("IPadress"), "Basic", New NetworkCredential("username", "password"))
WC.Credentials = CREDS
WC.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0;     Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;")

Try
    WC.DownloadFile("ftp://111.22.33.444/Folder/Folder/Folder/UPLOAD/File1.pdf","myFile.pdf")
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

This code runs in Windows App successfully, But in asp.net it gives an error that "REMOTE SERVER RETURNED AN ERROR: (404) Not Found"

Please help. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you get on the web server and successfully ftp (from the command line or FTP app) to this address and access the pdf file with these credentials?

Comment: Yes offcourse I can access it from ftp easily, but not working in asp.net

Answer (score 1):

WebClient is for the http protocol.  I believe you need to use FtpWebRequest instead.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229711%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for documentation and example usage.  If your ftp login places you in a subdirectory by default, you may want to see [this article](http://www.colourcoding.net/blog/archive/2010/01/25/ftpwebrequest-and-550-file-unavailable-e.g.-file-not-found-no.aspx) for a work around.

Comment: there is no error in this code but the pdf file is not shown on the webpage. Then where is the code Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd()) is writing the file ?? How could I see the pdf file on the web page.. Please Help.

Comment: Please see my one more detailed question at :  How to show a pdf file in a web page present on secured web hosting